# Why is a separator not required in `for i do cmd; done`

Tags: bash, shell, language-lawyer

```
for i do echo $i; done
```

How is this even legal?  (I would expect it to be written with an extra semi-colon `for i; do echo $i; done`) It works in bash, dash, zsh, and ksh.  The standard (by which I mean http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) states:

```
The for loop requires that the reserved words do and done be used to
delimit the sequence of commands.  The format for the for loop is as follows:

    for name [ in [word ... ]]
    do
        compound-list
    done
```

So clearly when "in word" is omitted, `do` is serving as a separator.  So the implication seems to be that the separator (the newline) after the `[ in [word .. ]]` actually belongs inside the closing right bracket.  Can someone point to anything in the standard which justifies this (IMO) horrible abuse of the language?

Comment: @willian: oops, forgot that my dupe vote would be a hammer. But I think my earlier question does cover exactly the same ground, possibly with a different editorial slant. Let me know if you disagree.

Comment: Not only is my question a dupe of yours, it is far less rigorously asked!

Comment: @rici What about the semi-colon in `for ((i=0;i<5;++i)) do echo foo; done`?

Comment: @pesathe: iirc, there is a deprecated bash extension which allows that semicolon to be omitted.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the [GNU `man` page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html), you see the loop has this syntax:

```
for

    The syntax of the for command is:

    for name [ [in [words …] ] ; ] do commands; done
```

So as you can see the extra semi-colon is part of the optional section.

---

The [linux-die man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) states the same.

Comment: maybe because the `;` semicolon is required to indicate the end of variable argument list and `do` can be a valid argument (`for i in a do c; do echo $i;done`), but as without in the argument of for is `"$@"` delimiter is no more required

Comment: also the undocumented bash syntax `for i;{ echo $i;}`,which is used by golfers, is shorter

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps someone else can fill you in on the history of the syntax, but in shell scripting, space characters (by default) are the delimiters. The `;` character is just a statement separator. It's often used instead of a newline to write logic as a "one-liner". Semicolons at the end of a line in a shell script are superfluous as *both* are command separators.

Also worth noting is the bracket syntax above is meant to indicate that those parts of the syntax are optional (i.e. you don't actually use brackets in the script there).

Finally, I find it's good to think of shells as... well, shells. You can write scripts with them and as "languages" they're Turing complete, but the syntax is often kind of funky.

Comment: Good point re: separator vs. delimiter.  It's interesting that the standard uses the phrase 'do and done be used to delimit', when "separate" would have been a more appropriate word.